# Enhancing Stack Overflow blog search: filtering out test entries

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, blog

In the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) search, upon entering the keyword "Test", I was presented with a compilation of blog post titles.
However, it's worth noting that among these results, two entries namely [test](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/14/__trashed/) and [Test post hello world](https://stackoverflow.blog/undefined/test-post), appear to be non-genuine blog posts, likely generated for testing purposes.
It would greatly enhance the search experience if these test-related entries were omitted from the search results.

**Screenshot of search result with the blog post URL:**

> [image: Test posts]

Comment: Why omit them rather than just unpublishing them??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test-related entries have been unpublished now.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: I've edited the post to indicate that the posts were actually unpublished, judging from the fact that the links to those posts in the question now return an error message.